# jsp command <%=%> being ignored when it is used in a Javascript statement, inside a taglib tag statement?

Tags: java, javascript, jsp, taglib

An example will make this clearer!

The jsp file...

```
<%@ taglib prefix ="jam" uri= "http://jam.tld" %>
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%
     String targetPage = true ? "toast" : "bread"; 
%>

<jam:text onmousedown="movePage('<%=targetPage%>');" id="<%=targetPage%>"><%=targetPage%></jam:text>
```

Note - the taglib is not mine and I have no control over it. (it isn't really called jam either :).

This then creates this HTML...

```
<td onmousedown="movePage('<%=targetpage%>;');" id="toast">toast</td>
```

Which as you can see: the <%=targetPage%> was only replaced/parsed in the non-javascript bit?

The compiled jsp file looks like this:

```
jspx_th_jam_005ftext_005f2.setOnmousedown("movepage('<%=targetpage%>')");
```

Anyone know what is going on, or how to fix it?
Why is the `<%=%>` tag being ignored when it is part of JavaScript statement?
:)

Comment: Just a guess, try `onmousedown="movePage('${targetPage}');"` (using expression language)

Comment: No, that doesn't compile as JSP. Do you mean add jquery to the page and use that?

Comment: No, i mean using [expression language](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/el/info).

Comment: In your example output, looks like the replacement was done correctly inside `id="..."`, which uses only double quotes. In the `onmousedown="..."` there it is wrapped both by double and single quotes. Try `"movePage(\"<%=targetPage%>\");"`, i.e. escaped double quotes instead of single quotes.

Comment: Uooo can you please give an example?

Comment: geert3 - nope, that compiles to jspx_th_jam_005ftext_005f2.setOnmousedown("movePage(\"<%=targetPage%>\");");

Comment: @Uooo Thanks, have read up on EL now. It is not available to me. So no.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a bit of a cheat solution, you dont need the JSP tag in that JS call. In fact, it's tidier this way

```
<jam:text onmousedown="movePage(this.id);" id="<%=targetPage%>"><%=targetPage%></jam:text>
```

Comment: Good solution. However my example was simplified for clarity, sadly the id does not match the page name.